# Microsoft Word 2007: How do I change the default (automatic) border colour?

Tags: microsoft-word, colors, default-settings, border

I have "In Line with Text" images with borders in my document, but the only way to add those borders is through the Paragraph > Borders and Shading option, rather than through the Picture Tools > Format section. Because of that, the automatic border colour is set to black, and won't save any other colour I choose for it. When I open up the document again, all borders have reverted to black.

Is there any way to change the default border colour, or some other means of adding colour borders to in-line images?

Comment: Sorry to say, but in 2023 the situation is still the same.

Comment: This is the way Outlook (up to now Outlook 365) has worked for many years.

Answer (score 0):

I no longer have Word 2007 on my system, but Word 2010 and 2021 both allow color borders on in-line-with text images and they are controlled on the [Picture Format or (Picture Tools > Format) tab](https://addbalance.com/word/ribbons.htm#Picture). The preceding link is to my page on ribbon tabs and shows them for 2007 and on.

[image: screenshot of Word 2007 Picture Format tab]

The tab above should appear when you have the picture selected. You can use the Border controls.

"Automatic" in color selections is black for light backgrounds and white for dark backgrounds.

When I change the color of the border in a document and save it, then reopen, the color persists in the opened document. Here is one where I changed the color to blue.
[image: screenshot]

This did not change the default color, though. Does this happen if you open Word in [safe mode](https://support.office.com/article/dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72)?

If you are saying that the color in a saved document reverts back, please save a sample document where this happens to a cloud location and post a view/share link for it here. That way we can examine it to see if there is something different.